# Request permission dialog send app to the background

Tags: android, android-permissions

I have Send SMS button where app ask user for `SEND_SMS` permission and then send SMS. But when I click Send SMS button app is send to the background and permission request dialog is shown at the home screen. When I click allow and go back to the app I have automatically navigated to the home fragment of the app. Any way if I go back to the fragment with Send SMS button not I can send SMS. (So permission grant is persisted.) My code will look like below

In `AndroidManifest.xml` I have

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

In MainActivity.kt

```
 fun requestSendSmsPermission() {

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS
            )
        ) {
            android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Permission Request")
            .setMessage("Reason for permission request")
            .setPositiveButton("ok"
            ) { _, _ ->
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    this@MainActivity,
                    arrayOf(Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS),
                    SEND_SMS_PERMISSION_CODE
                )
                sendSMS()
            }
            .setNegativeButton("cancel"
            ) { dialog, _ -> dialog.dismiss() }
            .create().show()
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this,
                arrayOf(Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS),
                SEND_SMS_PERMISSION_CODE
            )
            sendSMS()
        }

    }

    private fun sendSMS(){
        val emergencyContactNo = "1234567890"
        val messageBody =
            "hello there"
        val smsManager: SmsManager = SmsManager.getDefault()
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(emergencyContactNo, null, messageBody, null, null)
        Toast.makeText(this, "Message Sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }


  override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<String?>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        if (requestCode == SEND_SMS_PERMISSION_CODE) {
            if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission GRANTED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                sendSMS()

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission DENIED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }
```

In SMS sending fragment I have

```
mainActivity = activity as MainActivity

binding.btnSms.setOnClickListener {
     mainActivity.requestSendSmsPermission()
}
```

What I tried?

- I tried to use same code on new project there It worked fine. But in
  my project I am using Navigation architecture component.

To me it seems issue is with the navigation component and permission dialog combination. So how could I use runtime permission with navigation component?

Comment: Do you have any code in `onPause()` and `onStop()` which might cause this behavior ?

Comment: @ADM thanks for reaching out. no such code.

Comment: This is probably because the app crashed . I see you are calling `sendSMS()` just after requesting for permission which you should not . You should call `sendSMS()` only after you get the Permission granted . Remove all these kind of call to `sendSMS()` and it should work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is you are getting crash with `java.lang.SecurityException: Sending SMS message: does not have android.permission.SEND_SMS` .

Because you are calling `sendSms` synchronously just after requesting permission. You have to wait for permission to be granted or if its already granted the call `sendSms` right away.

Remove all `sendSms` call before permission is granted.  Checkout the [Basic Sample](https://github.com/android/permissions-samples/tree/main/RuntimePermissionsBasicKotlin).

```
fun requestSendSmsPermission() {
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)) {
        android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Permission Request")
            .setMessage("Reason for permission request")
            .setPositiveButton("ok"
            ) { _, _ ->
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    this@MainActivity,
                    arrayOf(Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS),
                    SEND_SMS_PERMISSION_CODE
                )
            }
            .setNegativeButton("cancel"
            ) { dialog, _ -> dialog.dismiss() }
            .create().show()
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            this,
            arrayOf(Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS),
            SEND_SMS_PERMISSION_CODE
        )
    }
}
```